# Working with SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

So I am working with `SWrevealViewController`. It is working well but I have an issue when the rear `view` is drawn or toggled it pushes the front `view` to the right, it does not slide over the front `view`.

**How do I make it slide over the front view?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm operating with the assumption that you don't want to modify the library yourself. SWRevealViewController doesn't support that style by default. You should consider an alternative library that does what you want such as [SlideMenuControllerSwift](https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift).

I'm not endorsing this library. I've never used it, but it has plenty of stars on GitHub and seems to achieve your desired effect.